# Is there a way to populate non-column member using a query in Spring JPARepository?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have the following structure :

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Action {
...
}
```

And than few entities extending Action, for example :

```
@Entity(name="chemistry")
public class Chemistry extends Action implements Serializable {
...
}
```

In order to execute the persistance I used JPARepository :

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ActionRepository<T extends Action> extends JpaRepository<T, String> {
...
}
```

And an interface for the children :

```
@Component 
@Service
@Repository
interface ChemistryRepository extends ActionRepository<Chemistry> {
}
```

The persistance mechanism works fine for all the entities inheriting from Action. 
Now I have a problem. 
I have another table in the DB, called 'action_params', including additional key-value parameters which related to a specific action (i.e. chemistry).
I have the appropriate entity :

```
@Entity(name="action_params")
public class ActionParams implements Serializable {
...
}
```

In the DB I cannot use foreign key since the key is not related to a specific table but any table inherits from Action. this is ok, I would like to use a query in order to get for each Action the records from the table action_params, based on its id.

And I would like to add a List to Action, mapping those records as a list. I tried using hibernate but any query returns empty (The following code was added into Action class):

```
@OneToMany
@JoinFormula(value="select p from action_params p where p.action_id = id")
@Transient
protected List<ActionParams>  actionParamsList;
```

This is not working. I also tried to autowire the ActionParamsRepository into Action, but of course there is no way doing it and I could not think of any other way.

Your advice will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What strong reason you have to use a JPA relation?

If there is no such reason, I'd suggest you to implement a new finder method in the ActionParams repository. Something like this:

```
@Query("select p from action_params p where p.action_id = :actionId")
List<ActionParams> findAllByActionId(@Param("actionId") Long actionId )
```

I suppose the type is Long. Replace it if you have other type.

Comment: I tried, but how can I invoke findAllByActionId from within Action?

Comment: @Maya: Of course repository should be called not from Action. I suppose you have some service that uses repositories to access data. The ActionParams should also be loaded by such service: Service will call repository and will load ActionParams for a given *actionId*.

Comment: Sure, I need another service. The existing one deals with Actions, now I need to have another one to be used as a proxy to Action.

Comment: @Maya: I would say - no. It is not necessary to have service per entity type. Service should be responsible for some business use case or group of similar use cases. In our case Action and ActionProperties entities are both related to Action. That's why you can implement operations on ActionProperties in the sames service as operations on Action entities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@Formula**, so let me explain, when you put a query on the formula, in Hibernate is added a subquery.

```
@Formula("(SELECT p FROM action_params p WHERE p.action_id = id)")
private List<ActionParams>  actionParamsList;
```

Comment: I Tried it with the same result as using JoinFormula. No record is back, the list is empty

Comment: did  you see your hibernate logs? could you please add in your question?